# Referring to the static class in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following situation. I want to be able to define a static method on a base class (register) which uses references to other static properties, which should be overridden. For example:

```
class Base {
    constructor() { }
    public static name = "Override me please";
    public static register = function() { console.log( Base.name ) }
}

class Child extends Base {
    constructor() { super() }
    public static name = "Child";
}
```

And then I of course would like Child.register() to print out 'Child'. Is it possible to get a reference to the current class? I know I can always pass in a reference to the class, but that seems less elegant than being able to refer to the class directly.

Any help appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation that does what you seem to be after.

```
class Base {
    constructor() { }
    public static aname = "Override me please";
    public static register = function() { console.log( this.aname ) }
}

class Child extends Base {
    constructor() { super() }
    public static aname = "ChildName";
}
```

There are 2 things to note.

1. The way JavaScript `this` binding works. When you call `Child.register()`, `this` will essentially refer to whatever is on the left of the `.`. In this "static" context, this will refer to the "constructor" function in the generated JavaScript, which is the "Class" in the TypeScript.
2. Because `this` refers to a function (in the JavaScript), `name` is a standard attribute of the function, and your naming of the property probably needs changing (though, this may not be standard, according to the [MDN documentation on function.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)). The fact that you have the value of the `Child.name = "Child"` may have masked this.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't realize 'this' refers to the class. What else could it refer to? And good catch on name vs. aname.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `constructor` property which is available on all JavaScript function's `prototype` and therefore the instances `__proto__`:

```
class Base {
    constructor() { }
    public static name = "Override me please";
    public static register = function() { console.log( Base.name ) }
}

class Child extends Base {
    constructor() { 
        super();
        console.log(this.constructor['name']); // use local version
     }
    public static name = "Child";
}

var child = new Child();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the class reference to work within a static function. From within an instance, it's trivial to call this.name.

Comment: Would this break if your class has a member named `name` or if your code gets minified? I might be reading this wrong but that's the impression I got from the MDN docs on `function.name` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)